# check if a class exists

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to check in manifest files if a given class exists?

I want to do something like this:

```
class foo {
    if exists( Class["foo::${lsbdistcodename}"] ) {
        include foo::${lsbdistcodename}
    }
}
```

So I can easily add distrubution / version specific classes which are then automatically included.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use defined instead of exists statement.
The following snippet works for me:

```
class foo {
    if defined( "foo::${lsbdistcodename}") {
            notify {'defined':}             
            include "foo::${lsbdistcodename}"
    }
}

class foo::precise {
    notify{'precise':}
}
```

[assuming you're running puppet version > 2.6.0]

Comment: Well thanks, but that will not work 'cause the class is not defined yet. That's the whole point of my question. I want to check if the class exists and I can include it. The code you posted will effectively not do anything at all. If the class is not included, the condition is false, and if it was included, include will not include it again...

Comment: does not work for me. I'm running puppet 2.7.18:


    `if defined(Class['common']) { notice('yes') }`

will output nothing, while

    `include common`
    `if defined(Class['common']) { notice('yes') }`

outputs 'yes'

Comment: Alright, so it seems that `defined("class")` checks whether a class exists, and `defined(Class["class"])` checks whether it was loaded.
Thank you for you help!